# Load price ticker into Pandas dataframe with DatetimeIndex

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I wonder if there is a simple way to load json data into Pandas DataFrame with DateTimeIndex.

```
data={"date":1405699200,"high":0.0045388,"low":0.00403001,"open":0.00404545,"close":0.00435873,"volume":44.34555992,"quoteVolume":10311.88079097,"weightedAverage":0.00430043},..]
```

The first column is Timestamp. I want to Pandas load it as DateTimeIndex.
Is it possible? I tried something like that:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data, index=['date'])
```

But without success.
Thanks.

Comment: Remember that in pandas almost everything is already implemented, and usually a google search is more effective (and faster) than asking on Stack. That said, you should look at [read_json](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_json.html), particularly the `convert_dates` parameter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this github issue](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/pull/16487), it seems not implemented yet to specify a data type for a specific column in the data frame constructor; As a work around, you can use `astype` and pass a dictionary a parameter to convert the data type of a column after the data frame has been constructed:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data).astype({'date': '<M8[s]'}).set_index('date')
df
```

[image]

Comment: It creates RangeIndex.

Comment: You can use `set_index` to set certain column(s) as index.

Answer (score 1):

How about this solution? Seems like your `data` variable is a list so this is based off of that:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data, index=pd.to_datetime([i.get('date') for i in data], unit= 's'))


                        close        date      high      low      open  \
2014-07-18 16:00:00  0.004359  1405699200  0.004539  0.00403  0.004045   

                      quoteVolume    volume  weightedAverage  
2014-07-18 16:00:00  10311.880791  44.34556           0.0043  


DatetimeIndex(['2014-07-18 16:00:00'], dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq=None)
```

Comment: It works. And it is good answer if there is no better solution without for-loop.

Answer (score 0):

You can convert the `date` column to `datetime` and set it as the dataframe's index:

```
df1 = df.assign(date=pd.Timestamp.fromtimestamp(df.date)).set_index('date')
```

At this point, the index of the dataframe `df1` is the `date` column and is a `DateTimeIndex` object.

```
print(df1.index)
# DatetimeIndex(['2014-07-18 12:00:00'], dtype='datetime64[ns]', name='date', freq=None)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can convert your timestamp to datetime.

```
import datetime as dt
import pandas as pd
data={"date":1405699200,"high":0.0045388,"low":0.00403001,"open":0.00404545}
data['date'] = dt.datetime.fromtimestamp(data['date']).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S') 
df = pd.DataFrame(data, index=['date'])
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up with:

```
df = pd.read_json(url, orient='records', convert_dates=True)
df.index = df['date']
```

Thanks.